# Flight delay compensation in Europe?

Tags: eu, delays, compensation, passenger-rights

My wife and I traveled with Wizz Air last month from Keflavik (IS) to Budapest (HU) and our flight was delayed for 4.5 hours. We are indian nationals with residency in Hungary.

Are we eligible for any compensation under EU rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Wizz Air is headquartered in Hungary, an EU member state, and is therefore covered by the [EU air passenger rights](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm).

(Also, even though Iceland is not an EU member, its membership of the EEA means that its airlines are bound by the same rules).

Comment: The fact that the flight was by an EU airline *into* the EU would trigger compensation rights regardless of whether Iceland is bound by them or not.

Comment: @Moo: Correct -- so there are two _separate_ reasons why this flight is covered: It is by an EU/EEA airline into the EU/EEA, and it departs from an EU/EEA airport.

Comment: What sort of compensation are we talking about?

Comment: @pbu: For a flight between 1500 and 3500 km, a cash compensation of 400 euro per traveler,